# How can I change n_steps while using stable baselines3 (PPO implementation)?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, stable-baselines

I am implementing PPO from stable baselines3 for my custom environment. Right now n_steps = 2048, so the model update happens after 2048 time-steps. How can I change this, I want my model to update after n_steps = 1000?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this as a parameter:

```
PPO(n_steps=1000)
```